Angular does not stop loading when using socket.io
I use socket.io-client in 1 service connect to python and i dont't know why if i connect to the server, my page will loading and do not expose any element. I used postmant to test, it still normal
I tried config proxy by create "proxy.config.json" file and run with "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json"
I tried remove or add transport (do not use long-polling but it had same result)
It still log "Connected to Websocket" in Vscode website still loading. Somebody helps me, i'm really hopeless
This is my code:
`
 private socket: any;

 private readonly socketUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

private messageServerSubject: Subject<{status: string, road: string}> = new 
Subject<{status: string, road: string}>();
public messageServer$ = this.messageServerSubject.asObservable();

constructor() {
  this.connect(); 
}

private connect(): void {
this.socket = io(this.socketUrl, {transports: ['websocket'], reconnection: false});

this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to WebSocket');
});

this.socket.on('connect_error', (error: any) => {
  console.error('Connection error:', error);
});

this.socket.on('image_processed', (responseMessage: { status: string, road: string }) => {
  console.log(responseMessage);
  this.messageServerSubject.next(responseMessage);
});

}`
This is my proxy config:
{
"/socket.io": {
  "target": "http://localhost:5000",
  "ws": true,
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug"
}

}
